# Why 'go to source' reaching the end of the correspondig frame in Beamer in TexStudio?

Tags: beamer, texstudio

### 'Go to Source':

Which allows to go the right source code when you right click and choose the option 'go to source' in TexStudio pdf viewer.

It works well and good in other classes such as `article, report, etc`.

But in beamer, this gets me only to the end of the corresponding frame not the exact source code.

> Why 'go to source' reaching the end of the corresponding frame in Beamer in Tex Studio?

Comment: Because beamer processes only whole framea and ships them.  There is nothing you can do.

Comment: Oops...Its little tough work with this when `allowframebreaks` is on.'

Comment: @David `allowframebreaks` is evil :)

Comment: @Johannes_B Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Thats true. But when you have meterial in hand and when you want to prepare the slides immediately that helps. Especially when you lecture.